# Error: ADB exited with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, dart

Недавно приобрел смартфон Xiaomi Poco C65 6/128GB. Активировал режим разработчика. Включил одну опцию "отладка по USB", затем вторую "установка через USB". После запуска Run main.dart в Android Studio появляется ошибка

> Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install

При выполнении этого когда на смартфоне Samsung ошибки нет, все нормально. **Возможно, нужно какие-то опции включить или выключить в настройках смартфона.** Скриншот прикрепил. Если у кого-то была такая проблема, напишите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эта распространенная проблема Xiaomi. Погуглите, ответ точно найдете